# Changing the data in URL strings - Using API for database requests

Tags: javascript, json, mootools, concatenation

Using an API I am creating a forum using Javascript.

When a user clicks on the thread title on the `index.html` page they are taken to a page called `thread.html` on here I am using an API call to display the results for the thread with ID 1

```
var threadRequest = new Request.JSON({
  url: 'control.php?action=getThread&id=1',
  onSuccess: threadSuccess
    }).send();
```

My question is how would I change this so it knows which thread has been clicked so it knows which thread to call, I have tried

```
function callThread(thread){
  var threadRequest = new Request.JSON({
    url: 'control.php?action=getThread&id='+thread,
    onSuccess: threadSuccess
     }).send();
}
```

with `thread` being the foreign key in the table linked to the API.

The thread titles are displayed like so

```
var jsonRequest = new Request.JSON({
    url: 'control.php?action=getThreadList',
    onSuccess: ajaxSuccess

}).send();
```

This is the threadSuccess function as well

```
function threadSuccess (jArray){
    jArray.each(function(post){
        var postObject = new PostItem(post.id, post.name, post.comment, post.thread);
        postObject.display().inject($('postList'));
    })
}
```

My question is do you get it so that the url string would do something like `url: 'control.php?action=getThread&id=what ever number thread the user has clicked on`

The post table contains the fields id, name, comment, timestamp and thread (this will define which thread the post will be in.)

and a thread table contains id and title.

Comment: is there a question in this? when you say you tried, did it not work? what didn't work? seems reasonable and straightforward - ignoring the `why` and what you expose from the server, seo etc. one thing you can do is set url to `control.php`, method to `get` and pass an object as `data` with key->value pairs, easier to manage

Comment: My question is what do I need to do so it does something like `url: 'control.php?action=getThread&id=what ever number thread the user has clicked on'`In other words if the user clicks on thread number 5 is will add a 5 after the equals sign.

Comment: No errors came when it didn't work the screen was just blank,in other words the query failed.

Answer (score 0):

When you're outputting your links, do something like:

```
<div class="thread" data-id="{{ID from database}}">Thread</div>

document.querySelector('.thread').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id');
    callThread(id);
}, false);
```

The question you're asking is slightly confusingly worded, but this is the way I'd approach it if I were trying to achieve what I think you are!